# Send JSON Object with parameters

Tags: android, json

In my application I am trying to send JSONObject with parameters like UserId, Can anyone please suggest me some tutorials from where I can take some help...

I got this code but in this code I am only able to send the JSONObject not the parameters..

my url is like this: http://www.example.com/JSONObject/userId

how can i pass the JSONObject with the userId to the server..

```
public class HTTPPoster {
    public HttpResponse doPost(String url, JSONObject jsonProfilo) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpEntity entity;
        StringEntity s = new StringEntity(jsonProfilo.toString());
        s.setContentEncoding((Header) new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        entity = s;
        request.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean " I am only able to send the JSONObject not the parameters." , you can put all your parameter in the JsonObject itself, I am not getting what is your real problem

Answer (score 0):

In JSONObject you can keep your parameters like:

```
JSONObject jsonvalue =new JSONObject();
jsonvalue.put("userId", "urUserId");
```

Sample Code,here i m sending the server imeiNumber , userName and paasword:

```
JSONObject jsonvalue =new JSONObject();
jsonvalue = new JSONObject();
jsonvalue.put("imeiNumber", "00000000000");
jsonvalue.put("userName", mUserName);
jsonvalue.put("plainPassword", mPassword);
```

My point was similarly u can send userId and globalId to server.

Now in ur HttpConnection:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
String urlParameters = "body"
    + URLEncoder.encode(jsonvalue.toString(), "UTF-8");       
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
    "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));

try {
     OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
     os.write(jsonvalue.toString().getBytes());
     os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: will putting my userId in JSONObject do the job? as my URL is like: www.example.com/api/JSONObject/userId

Comment: ofcourse u can keep userid and other details  in ur json ....it will work perfectly

Comment: i had a word with my php developer and he said i need the userId seperate as a String not in jsonobject

Comment: In jsonobject he can get userId in form of string....I am not getting this point...can u bit elaborate wtz the purpose of sending the userid separately??

Comment: http://myevent.co/api/bookingseats/:json/:userId/:otherId this is my link where i have to insert the values in josn my jsonobject in userId my id and in otherId i have a global id that i have to pass please checkit out in this the userId is 17 and otherId is 95

Comment: userId and globalId these are the two values u need to send the server...u can send  both jsonvalue.put("globalId", "urglobalId"); and jsonvalue.put("userId", "urUserId");

Comment: and then what about the main json? can you please post me some sample code so that i can understand it....

Comment: then where I'll put the jsonvalue??